# How return string by execute SQL query in dapper

Tags: asp.net-core, dapper

.Execute(sQuery,...) in Dapper returns integer.

```
string sQuery = "SELECT FirstName FROM Customers WHERE Id = @Id";
```

How can I implement this to return FirstName?

Comment: use `Query` to get desired result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For executing query with Asp.Net Core and Dapper, try `SqlConnection` with `Query`.

Here is complete code.

```
using Dapper;

public class CustomersController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public CustomersController(ApplicationDbContext context
        , IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _context = context;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    // GET: Customers/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
        {
            string sQuery = "SELECT Name FROM Customer WHERE Id = @Id";
            var customer = connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<string>(sQuery, new { Id = id});
        }
        //Rest Code
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

> **Execute** is an extension method which can be called from any object of type `IDbConnection`. It can execute a **command** one or multiple times and **return the number of affected rows**.

***emphasis mine***

Execute can't be used for what you are asking.

Use one of the `Query*` based calls to get desired result

For example

```
string sQuery = "SELECT FirstName FROM Customers WHERE Id = @Id";

using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection("connection string")) { 
    var firstName = connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<string>(sQuery, new { Id = 1 });

    //...
}
```

Comment: i'm new to .net core can't implement this by using dapper

Comment: then with out execute method can't implement this by using dapper

Comment: @DulangaHeshan dapper provides many extension methods; one of those is `Execute`, but *that's the wrong one* and doesn't do what you want; the method you want - provided by dapper - is: `QueryFirstOrDefault`. The `<string>` tells it what a row should look like. Other methods starting with `Query...` exist for different scenarios. In your case, since you're probably expecting zero or one matches, this is a "first or default" scenario.

Comment: @DulangaHeshan to be more specific: `Execute` is for when you are performing something like an `insert` or `update` and *aren't expecting a result grid*. A result grid from a `select` statement is where the `Query...` part comes in: you are issuing a *query*.

Comment: @DulangaHeshan What do you mean by **can't implement this by using dapper**? Do you mean there is no `SqlCeConnection` or `QueryFirstOrDefault`?